# Validate file for record count in trailer

Tags: shell-script

I tried to write a script that should verify total detail records equal to the `Record_count` in trailer record and if unmatched throw error.

sample data:

```
HDR9185        20210601094001202105311.11j

DTL226-42742-14                        32.389185        NM30100000178103      D207935784ZAG Desjardins Trust              CAD      5470.34       32.38A E  2.0500      5549.4420220215NESBITT BURNS INC A/C 226-42742-14 (5H94798)                                                                            C      5014.0020170215N30100000178103                5H94798   ILPYA7SM71 
                   
DTL210-86993-11                        21.979185        NM30100000187369      D207989578ZAG Desjardins Trust              CAD      5036.97       21.97N A  2.0500      5117.8120220315NESBITT BURNS INC ITF A/C 210-86993-11 (5J10948)                                                                        C      5015.0020170315N30100000187369                5J10948   ILQETLZDH1 
                  
TRL      02         93084.00
```

The trailer record with `02` is the record count.

My code:

```bsh
if ! awk -F "|" ' /^HDR/ { h++; next; } /^TRL/ {t++; next} END { exit( (h != 1) || t != 1 || $NF != NR - 2 ); }' sample.txt
then
   echo "file did not pass validation test"
   exit 1
fi
 echo "Validated successfully"
```

This is throwing me the standard output as "file did not pass validation test" even if my records match the trailer count or unmatched.

Comment: `$NF` is the `93084.00`, not the `02`.

Comment: Can you please confirm that your data are accurately represented here? Do you really have a blank line after every line of data?

Comment: no I dont have a blank line of data ...it came while formating the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to assume that the data uses `|` as field delimiter, which it clearly does not.  It appears as if you want to assert that there is exactly *one* head record (`HDR...`) and *one* tail record (`TRL`) and that the tail record mentions the correct number, which is the number of intermediate data records (`DTL...`).

I'm going to assume that the file could possibly contain empty lines and that these should be ignored.

The `awk` program:

```c
$1 ~ /^HDR/ { h++ }
$1 ~ /^DTL/ { d++ }
$1 == "TRL" { t++; ok = (d == $2) }
END { exit !(h == 1 && t == 1 && ok) }
```

For each `HDR...` record, `h` is incremented.  For each `DTL...` record, `d` is incremented.  When a `TRL` record is found, we increment `t` and then compute a boolean value in `ok` that tells us whether the number of data lines are correct or not.

The `END` block exits the program with an exit status that will be zero (success) if we've come across exactly one header and tail record each and if that boolean `ok` value is *true*.

The following code additionally exits with a non-zero exit status if any records appear out of order (while allowing for zero data records):

```c
BEGIN { ok = 1 }
$1 ~ /^HDR/ { h++; ok = (h == 1 && d ==  0 && t == 0) }
$1 ~ /^DTL/ { d++; ok = (h == 1            && t == 0) }
$1 == "TRL" { t++; ok = (h == 1 && d == $2 && t == 1) }
!ok { exit }
END { exit !(h == 1 && t == 1 && ok) }
```

This keeps rack of the overall validity of the data in the boolean `ok` variable and exits with a non-zero exit status as soon as this variable flips over to *false* (or with a zero exit status if it remains *true* throughout the running of the code). We still need to make sure that exactly one head and tail record has been seen when reaching the `END` block, or it would validate an empty file as ok.

To run either of the above `awk` programs, put it in a file (here `validate.awk`) and use

```bsh
if awk -f validate.awk sample.txt; then
    echo 'file ok'
else
    echo 'file not validated'
fi
```

Alternatively, give the whole program on the command line as a single-quoted string:

```bsh
if awk '$1 ~ /^HDR/ { h++ } $1 ~ /^DTL/ { d++ } $1 == "TRL" { t++; ok = (d == $2) } END { exit !(h == 1 && t == 1 && ok) }' sample.txt
then
    echo 'file ok'
else
    echo 'file not validated'
fi
```

---

Addressing [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657382/validate-file-for-record-count-in-trailer/657394?noredirect=1#comment1237739_657394) saying that the `TRL` record may look like `TRL0009 93084.00` where `0009` is the count of all types of records.

In this case, the first `awk` program may instead look like

```c
$1 ~ /^HDR/ { h++ }
$1 ~ /^DTL/ { d++ }
$1 ~ /^TRL/ { t++; ok = ( d == substr($0,4,4) - 2 ) }
END { exit !(h == 1 && t == 1 && ok) }
```

Here, `substr($0,4,4)` is used to pick out the string starting at position four, of length four, in `$0` (the original input line). We subtract 2 from this number to account for the head and tail records.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the coding ...I see some syntax issues while running the above code  in line 6    --> Syntax error at line 6 : `(' is not expected.                                                                                                                                          
     1  #!/bin/sh
     2
     3  awk
     4  $1 ~ /^HDR/ { h++ }
     5  $1 ~ /^DTL/ { d++ }
     6  $1 == "TRL" { t++; ok = (d == $2) }
     7  END { exit !(h == 1 && t == 1 && ok) } sample.txt

Comment: Can you please help to fix ...because looks like the '(' placing seems right to me.

Comment: @Flower See added info at the end of the answer.

Comment: Actually my file seems to have trailer record_record count w.r.t position.filed value is positioned as (4–11) with length 8.So my trailer record can display in below forms ---TRL0009         93084.00  (TRL is the record_type with position 1-3) and record_count with position(4-11).  The other way the trailer record can come as  below                
TRL  09         93084.00. So if we use the code as $2 , $1 == "TRL" { t++; ok = (d == $2) it might cause issues...how can we check it position based.(Total no of records in trailer record count = sum of records include header n trailer as well.

Comment: can u please help with my above issue.

Comment: @Flower See added bit at the end.

Comment: ,I tried with input file with recordcount as 11 including header n trailer. My sample trailer record -->    TRL011         93084.00 (script failed to validate and said mismatch eventhough its 11).  code used is below                                                                                      if awk '$1 ~ /^HDR/ { h++ } $1 ~ /^DTL/ { d++ } $1 == "TRL" { t++; ok = ( d == substr($0,4,8) ) } END { exit !(h == 1 && t == 1 && ok) }' sample.txt

Comment: @Flower Well, it seems as if you have modified the `substr()` call from `substr($0,4,4)` to `substr($0,4,8)`.

Comment: actually my length of record count is 8 so is it right to use 8.                                                                 The record_count field starts from 4th till 11th position of length 8 .Should we give it as 4 or 8 now ?

Comment: @Flower Sorry, but I can't help you further. It is clear that the information that you are giving us about the exact formatting of your data is limited and at times incorrect or not entirely correct. It is difficult to develop code to parse a data file with an unknown or seemingly changing format. If you want further help relating to this particular issue, consider opening a new question and be sure to give examples using _actual_ data (make sure there is no private or personal information in the data though).

Comment: ,Thanks for your help .I will try posting again

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```bsh
if awk -v RS='' '$1 == "TRL" {exit !($2 == (NR - 2))}' file; then
  echo "success"
else
  echo "invalid"
fi
```

awk's `RS = ""` means each record is separated by empty lines (aka "paragraph mode")

I originally did have an explanation for the statement

```c
exit !($2 == (NR - 2))
```

but you have similar code in your question so I figured you were OK with it. Anyway:

- For the trailer record count to be valid, the whole file must have that count plus the header plus the trailer exactly.
- the number of records in the whole file is the awk NR variable
- subtract two, that should be the count in the trailer.
- like C, an arithmetic comparison operator returns 1 for success/0 for failure
- the shell considers exit status 0 is success, non-zero is failure
- so we negate the return code of the `==` operator

---

I just realized my code does not account for any record that appears *after* the trailer, which probably should invalidate the file: try this

```bsh
if awk -v RS='' '$1 == "TRL" {n = $2} END {exit !(n == NR - 2)}' file; then ...
```

Comment: Thank you,this works !!

Comment: Can you please explain this part of the code what exist ! means -->{exit !($2 == (NR - 2))}

Comment: instead of $2 ,is there anyways to check my position.E.g Input data in trailer record comes as  -->TRL00002         93084.00   or TRL      02         93084.00,                is it possible to validate the trailer record count w.r.t position(Like trailer record count is from position 4 to 11) and its of number length 8

Comment: Instead of asking me and Kusalananda separate questions in comments (which is rude) ask a new question.