# Validate trailer record count

Tags: shell-script

I have a trailer record of format `TRL 4         93084.00` (In which first 3 positions are my `record_type` and position 4 to 11 is my `record_count` (of length 8) and position 12 to 28 is my `record_amt`.

How do I check if sum of my record count of my file to the `record_count` value of my trailer record matches or not?

My input file is as below:

```
HDR9185        20210601094001202105311.11j        
DTL226-42752-11                       100.499185        NM30100000115006     
DTL210-86995-19                        92.479185        NM30100000115030     
TRL 4         93084.00
```

code :

```
if awk '$1 ~ /^HDR/ { h++ } $1 ~ /^DTL/ { d++ } $1 == "TRL" { t++; ok = ( d == substr($0,4,8) ) } END { exit !(h == 1 && t == 1 && ok) }' sample.txt
```

While using above code though my count is 4 and matches with trailer count 4 ,it doesn't validate correctly.(not sure if its spacing issue to handle the 8 character length for record_count field  which has value of 1 character '4' remaining being treated as space)).

Can you help to fix my code

Comment: You've not defined the "_sum of my record count of my file_". Do you mean the number of lines in the file? Including or excluding the `HDR` line?

Comment: yes sum of or number of records of HDR,DTL and TRL should be equal to record_count value of TRL record in the file. In my above input file I have one HDR,one TRL and two DTL records totally 4 records that should match the record_count value in my traler record which is 4 in above case.

Comment: Note that the reason that you asked this question, which is slightly modified from your previous one, was that you had tail records that looked like `TRL0009` or `TRL011`. The example that you show now has `TRL 4`, which clearly is handled by my answer to your [original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657382/validate-file-for-record-count-in-trailer).  You just need to use `$2+2` in place of `$2`.  You need to _explain the various variations in the data format_, or you will leave everyone trying to read your mind again.

Comment: @kusalananda, thats why I have mentioned my record_value in terms of position ...it can be 00000009 or 09 or 9 (its position is 4-11 and record_count length is 8) which means if its 09 or 9 remaining length might be space (out of 8 characters),hope its bit more clear explanation now..

Comment: Add `+0` after the call to `substr()` to turn the zero-filled string of digits into a proper number.

Comment: Tried adding 0 ,if awk '$1 ~ /^HDR/ { h++ } $1 ~ /^DTL/ { d++ } $1 == "TRL" { t++; ok = ( d == substr($0,4,8) + 0 ) } END { exit !(h == 1 && t == 1 && ok) }' sample.txt.                    Still not validating successfully

Comment: what is the differences of this your question [Validate file for record count in trailer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657382/validate-file-for-record-count-in-trailer) with now opened one?

Comment: The intial one was not w.r.t positioning of characters. so the column vise stuff like using $2 worked ....but this requirement is for -->the count after TRL can be any integer in positions 4-11, with or without leading zeros, and leading and trailing spaces

Comment: @Flower doing `substr($0,4,8)` is the same as using `$2` there too whit exception that when you do `substr($0,4,8)` it will take input like `1 2 3 4 5 6` in `TRL 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc` while later will only take `1`, but you won't have such input as you showed the format of that line, so both should do the job and it then duplicated of the previous one.

Comment: thanks for ur comments when i triec using $2 it assumes that a separate column it works if the input is TRL 4         93084.00 .But if the input is TRL00000004 it doesnt work is what i saw whil executing -->ok = (d == $2) } END { exit !(h == 1 && t == 1 && ok).

Comment: OK, I retracted my close vote. and my downvote cannot be undo until you do an edit on your question. thanks for clarifying you may want show that kind of inputs in your question at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok

```
awk '
{
    ok += /^HDR/
    t += /^TRL/
}

t == 1 && ok == 1 {
    ok = int(substr($0, 4)) == FNR
}

ok != 1 || t > 1 {
    exit
}

END {
    exit ! (ok == 1 && t == 1)
}' file
```

Comment: Excellent that worked atlast :-) Thanks what does this line actually does..ok = 0 + substr($0, 4) == FNR   ($0 is 1st column and 4 is the 4th position FNR?

Comment: @Flower `0+...` (now changed to `int(...)`) takes the numeric value of `...`. `man awk` should explain the substr function. This makes the comparison with FNR (the current line number of the file) numeric instead of string based.

Comment: oh okie got it thank you for explaining.